# How do I copy and paste a template into the same google sheet weekly via script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Team takes notes weekly on a running document in which every week I have to re-copy and paste the template at the top for notes to be taken

script but have no eduation how to use

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a Template sheet hidden in your Spreadsheet.  Then with the following example script copy the template and make it the first sheet of the Spreadsheet.  I'll let you figure out the sheet name.

Then you could have a time based trigger to copy the Template once a week at a particular time.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Template");
    sheet = sheet.copyTo(spread);
    sheet.setName("New Sheet");
    sheet.activate();  // required to move the sheet
    spread.moveActiveSheet(1);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Sheet.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet))
- [Sheet.activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate)
- [Spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveActiveSheet(Integer))
- [Time based Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Hi im looking to do this in a document, not a sheet

Comment: Your title says `google sheet`.  And what do you mean by `the template at the top`